# Automate post creation in wordpress

Tags: shortcode

I have a database which has 2000 items. I would like to

a) create a page for each item

b) Create another page comparing two items. With 2000 items I can create thousands of pages.

I am from java programming background so my solution was to write code which will fetch all the items from the database
a) run in a loop and create the pages
b) run two loops and pass in if of items. Code will fetch details and create the pages.

My questions
Is the right way to go create searchable, SEO friendly page for each item ?

Where do I create the code to execute the desired functionality ?

Will it be a plugin or function or a script ?

Comment: what is the question, what are you trying to do and you can't figure out how to do it, or it doesn't work? your question right now includes about 5 different questions

Comment: I think you should use a dynamic method. Just create one page and display single or product comparison in it ex - `/something/` , product page - `/something/(product1)` & comparison - `/something/(product1-product2)`. You can handle request made to `/something/(*)` by creating a file on theme folder - `page-something.php`, and then parse the request and generate the page. The `(*)` value can be retrieved using $wp_query object.

Comment: I changed the language of question to make it more clear

Comment: I would probably do this dynamically too, but this is a very broad question. Maybe lookup "endpoints" here and in the WordPress Codex.